# Laravel Task Scheduling - when does the execution starts

Tags: laravel, scheduled-tasks, laravel-scheduler

Laravel Task Scheduling has options like, `everyMinute()` which will run a command every minute. I want to know what is the time it actually starts executing. Is it when I run the server or any specific second of the minute?
I am trying to run a function depending on the time difference. Here's a pseudocode

```
Run myCustomFunction() if diffInMin(now, customTime) <= 1
```

I thought it will run 1 time but it ran twice every time.

Comment: The scheduler runs via a cron task every minute so `everyMinute` executes when that happens. It's up to the OS to determine when that is. It's usually pretty accurate on the 0 second mark of that minute (on the OSs I tired it on) but may be off depending on server load

Comment: I logged the task handler and it shows it executes mostly at :03/:04 second of the minute. Not so accurate as I was running on my local machine. But I think you're right about it running at the beginning of the minute

Answer (score 1):

The scheduler usually runs every minute right around the zero secound mark based on the server's current time as @apokryfos mentioned.

Assuming the `customTime` is a fixed DateTime, what makes you think the code you wrote will only run once?

- When `now() === customTime` the `diffInMin()` would be zero so the
  condition `diffInMin(now, customTime) <= 1` will evaluate to true.
- The next minute, the `diffInMin()` would be 1, so the
  condition `diffInMin(now, customTime) <= 1` will still evaluate to true.

Comment: Thanks for pointing the minute different mistake. Could you tell me a better way to make sure the function runs once?

Comment: Can't really tell without knowing the full context. But since you said it is a command, adding something like `$schedule->command('name')->everyMinute();` in the `App\Console\Kernel` should be enough.